# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isNotDirty' of null WordPress error

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am having an issue with my WordPress installation. I am hoping some people familiar with WordPress can help me out.

I am trying to add custom CSS using the Visual Composer plugin but when I click save after entering the CSS it does not do anything.

If I delete everything and keep it as it was then it allows the save button to work. I have included the error in the console below.

After researching this a little bit I see that the `isNotDirty` property is part of tinyMCE. It detects if the CSS stored in the database has changed in the window.

To troubleshoot I have uninstalled all the plugins and reinstalled them. I have restored a previous known working database but am still getting the error. Any ideas on where to look next? I would have thought reinstalling visual composer would have corrected the issue but apparently not.

[Here is some info](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:property.tinymce.Editor.isNotDirty)

[Here is another link with more info](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.Editor.isDirty)

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'isNotDirty' of null composer-view.js?ver=4.2.2:293
vc.post_custom_css_block_view.Backbone.View.extend.setAlertOnDataChange composer-view.js?ver=4.2.2:293
vc.post_custom_css_block_view.Backbone.View.extend.save composer-view.js?ver=4.2.2:277
n.event.dispatch load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2,farbtastic&ver=3.9.1:3
r.handle load-scripts.php?c=0&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload,json2,farbtastic&ver=3.9.1:3
```

UPDATE:
I have installed a fresh copy of the theme on a different virtual host and it seems to be working fine on there. I noticed that the working version has one extra line of HTML which is listed below. The non working version does not have this.

```
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none;"></ul>
```

I changed the themes on the non-working version and it still does not work.

UPDATE:
Something very strange happened. I am always using the backend editor, so I decided I would try out the frontend editor to see if I could add custom CSS. Sure enough it allows you to do it and I was able to save the custom CSS. So I went back into backend editor mode and now all of a sudden the custom CSS in the backend is working.

Comment: `isNotDirty` is indeed part of TinyMCE, which Visual Composer uses, and in this case Visual Composer is trying to set the property on an object that is `null` and not an instance of `TinyMCE` so the issue is with Visual Composer. You should contact the developers to get a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I experience this issue on one of my Wordpress projects. I managed to fix it by taking the following steps:

- FTP to '/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/backend'
- Edit 'composer-view.js'
- Locate the following lines of code and remove them:

  1. (line 277 for me; may differ for you)

> ```
>    this.setAlertOnDataChange();
> ```

2. (line 291-295 for me; may differ for you)

> ```
>  setAlertOnDataChange: function() {
>     if(vc.saved_custom_css !== this.$editor.val() && window.tinymce) {
>       window.tinymce.get('content').isNotDirty = false;
>     }
>   }
> ```

- Save your changes to 'composer-view.js' but keep the file open as you'll need to undo these changes in a moment...
- Go back over to WordPress and refresh, making sure 'composer-view.js' in particular is refreshed and not cached in your browser, and try now to click the previously dead 'Save' button in the visual composer Custom CSS editor
- It should now work so make some changes (when I did it the only change I made was to remove the last line of CSS I added before the thing became unresponsive in the first place but perhaps any change will be accepted I don't know?...)
- Now, if everything is working as usual again, go back to 'composer-view.js' and undo the changes you made (i.e. put the above lines of code back in).
- Everything should now work as it did before – or at least it did for me.